# Replace text in multiple file extentions

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to replace some text in several files using sed.

For example: replacing *lion* with *hawk* in all txt and md files within a directory and its subdirectories.

So far I have from research the best (*non-working*) attempt I have is:

```
find . -type *.txt | xargs sed -i '' 's/lion/hawk/'
```

Also trying to add md to txt regex - *\.(txt|md) gives an error.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want

```
find . -type f \( -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.md' \) -exec sed -i 's/lion/hawk/g' {} \;
```

The `-o` is a logical OR on the two `-name` predicates. You can also directly use `-exec` instead of piping to `xargs` (both work).

**edit** updated quoting & parens.

Comment: +1 But using `+` instead of `\;` would be more efficient as it will send multiple files at a time to `sed` therefore calling it less often.

Comment: note that `find -exec` is much worse than `xargs` from performance standpoint - it will execute new `sed` instance for every file found, when `xargs` will combine many files into single `sed` call

Comment: @beer it won't work for me. It replaces the string `lion` only in the `.md` but not in the `.txt` file.

Comment: @mvp I assume you mean that the name matching is incorrect, but are backing away from your incorrect statement about `-exec` being less efficient than `xargs`. Okay.

Comment: @beerbajay You need to put single quotes around the filename patterns so they won't be expanded by the shell. And you should replace `\;` at the end by `+` for efficiency. See http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Multiple-Files.html

Comment: Thank you. Using Mac I first had to install GNU Command Line Tools for this to work. See http://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
find . -type f -regextype egrep -regex ".*\.(txt|md)" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' 's/lion/hawk/'
```

Important differences from your attempt:

- use `-type f` to limit search to files only
- use `-regextype` to set regex engine to `egrep` (smarter than default emacs)
- use `-regex ".*\.(txt|md)"` to limit search to files with `txt` or `md` extension
- use `find -print0` and `xargs -0` to handle spaces in files names properly

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to the below GNU find command,

```
find . -name *.txt -o -name *.md -type f | xargs sed -i 's/lion/hawk/g'
```

**Explanation:**

```
.                              #  Current directory

-name *.md -o -name *.md       # Filenames end with .txt or .md
-type f                        #   Only files.
xargs sed -i 's/lion/hawk/g'    #  Replace lion with hawk on the founded files.
```

Comment: It seems you are misunderstanding `mindepth`. `find`'s default behavior is to look into subdirectories. `mindepth` is used to restrict operations to depths that are *at least* that deep.